# PHP Store reference to abstract class in variable

Tags: php

1) Is it possible to store a reference to an abstract class in a variable like so:

```
abstract class A implements X {}

$A = A; //This doesn't work
```

2) Ultimately I want to be able to pass a reference to an abstract class to a method or function.

```
class Y { public function __construct(X $X){} }

$Y = new Y($A);
```

It would even be satisfactory to be able to do something like this:

```
abstract class A { public static $staticProperty; }

class Y {
    public function __construct($X){
        echo $X::$staticProperty; //Doesn't work
    }
}

$Y = new Y('A');
```

Comment: Erm. May I ask about what you going to do with this _reference_?

Comment: Access its properties

Comment: It would suffice if I could reference the abstract class from a variable. `$var = 'abstractClassName'; $var::$staticProp` doesn't work. I'll update question.

Comment: In fact, here's a [demo](http://ideone.com/UBCMOp) copied from the question as is (with minor change, setting a value for that prop). It works.

Comment: You are right, I msut have had a typo in my tests. Thanks. Can you post answer and link in an official answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you cannot instantiate an abstract class, you're restricted to working with static properties (and constants) only. And since PHP 5.3, you can use variables to specify the queried class, with [only restriction](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

> As of PHP 5.3.0, it's possible to reference the class using a
>   variable. The variable's value can not be a keyword (e.g. self, parent
>   and static).

So you can pass a classname instead; it will work as an anchor for an abstract class. For example ([demo](http://ideone.com/2gq5qI)):

```
abstract class Foo { static $bar = 5; }
abstract class Bah { static $bar = 6; }

function echoBar($classname) {
   echo $classname::$bar;
}

echoBar('Foo'); // 5
echoBar('Bah'); // 6
```